# Array deduplicate it by using integer value

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a small question, but not sure how to do it correctly:

if we have array = `["123.56","444.56","444.34","444"]`

what is the way to dedupe it then way that it will return:

- FROM: `["123.56","444.56","444.34","444"]`
- TO: `["123.56","444.34"]`

Potential Rules are:

- Convert string into floats

  - [123.56,444.56,444.34,444.0]
- Then dedupe value based on the INTEGER of it,

  - Basically treat like this:

    - FROM: `[123.56,444.56,444.34,444.0]`
    - TO: `[123,444,444,444]`
    - Deduplication result will be:
      - `[123,444]`
    - ***BUT now by using the above integers I need to get LOWEST from the group (+ avoid the whole number when will take lowest, but if the whole number is the only one from the group, then keep it e.g. like 444)***

      - 123 GROUP (123.56) = lowest 123.56
      - 444 GROUP (444.56,444.34,444.0) = lowest = 444.34 (not 444.0 !!!)
- Result = `["123.56","444.34"]`

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: @Sujay I came to the point of deduplication, that's it, not sure what will be the best approach + I'm not 100% sure if the steps which I have suggested are the correct way to do it, so any hit will be appreciated

Comment: @OksanaOk once you get [444.56,444.34,444.0] just sort it in ascending order and then get the first number greater then  444 ?

Comment: @SyedHussain and how will you come to di point? What will be the way to group the values from the array-based on their integer value?

Comment: if you remove details, you can't get lowest. you need to keep all the details (i.e. dont dedup). what you can do is just print the compact format you want, but in the backend keep all the details.

Comment: @Joshua so currently I'm fighting with the way to group the values without losing the initial data to do further sorting... not 100% sure how to.. :D

Comment: @OksanaOk I finally understand. but it is a little hard to do with such a small dataset. do you have a bigger dataset? maybe around 30-50 values?

Comment: Could you indicate of any of the answers below helped you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working:

```
import math
def second_smallest(numbers:list):
    numbers.sort()
    if len(numbers)==1:
        return numbers[0]
    else:
        return numbers[1]
l1=["123.56","444.56","444.34","444"]
l2=[float(j) for j in l1]
l1=list(set([int(math.trunc(float(j))) for j in l1]))
l2=[[float(x) for x in l2 if str(x).startswith(str(i))] for i in l1]
for i,j in enumerate(l2):
    l1[i]=str(second_smallest(j))
print(l1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with:

```
def dedupe(numbers):
    a  = sorted(numbers)
    b = [int(float(x)) for x in a]
    c = []
    for n in b:
        if b.count(n) > 1:
            if float(a[b.index(n)]).is_integer():
                c.append(a[b.index(n) + 1])
            else:
                c.append(a[b.index(n)])
        else:
            c.append(a[b.index(n)])
    return list(set(c))
```

I don't know if it is optimal but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the optimum solution but works fine

```
l = ["123.56","444.56","444.34","444"]
fl = []
groups = {i.split(".")[0] for i in l}
l = [float(i) for i in l]
groups = [float(g) for g in groups]
# print(l)
# print(groups)
for g in groups:
    gl = [i for i in l if g<=i<g+1]
    if len(gl)>1:
        gl.sort()
        al = [i for i in gl if i>g][0]
        fl.append(al)
    else:
        fl.append(gl[0])
print(fl)
```

output:

```
[123.56, 444.34]
```